# Visual Studio 2015 Breakpoint Offset When Debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I had faced an abnormal visual studio 2015 behavior, referring to the image attached below I was trying to place a breakpoint at line 1438, but right after I start debugging the workspace the breakpoint shifted to line 1440 instead which were affecting my code debugging process.

[Before Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl6PI.png)

[After Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztIRG.png)

Hope someone could assist on this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems likely that your source code if out of step with your built code. I.e. you failed to properly rebuild your program before starting to debug.

Comment: Or maybe you are debugging a release build. Shifting break points happen when the debugger determines that the line with the break point is not a valid line of code and it shifts the break point down to the next valid line of code. This can happen for various reasons including the two I suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I was running a debug build instead, and I did ensure that I recompile the whole solution before start debugging but the issue still persist. The line of code that I trying to break does not seems like a invalid code that the compile couldn't break.

Comment: Try setting a break point before that line and then stepping onto that line with the debugger. Doing that may give some clue as to what is happening.

Comment: I'm assuming you have optimisation turned off, that's the default for a debug build, but if you've turned optimisation on that would also explain this.

Comment: Hi john, thank you for the help but the answer from cup was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check your line endings - you probably have a mix of CRLF and LF and CR.  Visual studio debugger assumes that the line ending is the same throughout the code.  If it started as CRLF and the line in question just has LF, then the breakpoint will be in a different place.

Simple fix if you have Word.

1. open word
2. Open the source file in visual studio
3. Ctrl A, Ctrl X - get all the source from VS
4. In Word, Ctrl V - pasted in Word.  This will correct all the line endings
5. In Word, Ctrl A, Ctrl X - get all the code from word
6. In Visual Studio, Ctrl V - pasted back in visual studio
7. Save the source and rebuild

Comment: Thanks buddy, the suggestion was able to resolve the issue on my side.

Comment: Interesting, this is a new one to me.

Comment: This happens a lot when you are using source code control systems and cutting and pasting from comparison tools when resolving merge conflicts.  On installation, if some of the tools haven't been set up with the correct line endings, you will get a mish-mash.  It may not even be your fault.

Comment: @Cup Seems like a pretty big issue, is it fixed in later versions of VS? Would explain why I'm not aware of it.

Comment: This has been a problem since I started using Visual Studio with SVN, Perforce, Mercurial and GIT.